# Why are physical devices crashing my XCTest UI tests randomly?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

Recently, when writing new tests and testing on physical devices, eventually (sometimes within a few times of running tests or sometimes after hours of running tests) each device will start crashing. The only solution I have found is to restart the device and then the tests start running fine again.

Here is the console output from Xcode 7.3.1:

```
2016-07-22 09:17:27.277 XCTRunner[470:164209] Running tests...
2016-07-22 09:17:27.280 XCTRunner[470:164209] Unable to load configuration data from specified path /var/folders/83/tbqj_hp908ddc7bn45hcrh_c0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/B389F86E-56B0-4131-B52B-8E9A41E2A789/remote-container/tmp/CollaborateUITests-B389F86E-56B0-4131-B52B-8E9A41E2A789.xctestconfiguration; error: The file doesn’t exist.
2016-07-22 09:17:27.281 XCTRunner[470:164209] Looking for test bundles in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/15D4EDF6-C56A-4735-9DEF-57869AE677AC/CollaborateUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns
2016-07-22 09:17:27.281 XCTRunner[470:164209] Found test bundle at /var/containers/Bundle/Application/15D4EDF6-C56A-4735-9DEF-57869AE677AC/CollaborateUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/CollaborateUITests.xctest
2016-07-22 09:17:27.282 XCTRunner[470:164209] Looking for configurations in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/15D4EDF6-C56A-4735-9DEF-57869AE677AC/CollaborateUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/CollaborateUITests.xctest
2016-07-22 09:17:27.282 XCTRunner[470:164209] No configurations found, creating a default configuration that will run all tests.
2016-07-22 09:17:27.480 XCTRunner[470:164209] *** Assertion failure in -[XCUIApplication init], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/XCTest_iOS/XCTest-10112/XCTestFramework/UI Testing/XCUIApplication.m:72
```

And the pthread_kill:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x180620114 <+0>:  movz   x16, #0x148
    0x180620118 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x18062011c <+8>:  b.lo   0x180620134               ; <+32>
    0x180620120 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    0x180620124 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x180620128 <+20>: bl     0x1806066d8               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x18062012c <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x180620130 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #16
    0x180620134 <+32>: ret
```

Specifically, why am I seeing `Unable to load configuration data from specified path`? I do not get this error when the tests run as expected. What is changing on these devices? I have tried deleting the installed app and the XCTest helper app, but once a device starts showing these errors, the only way to solve the problem is to restart the device.

I can still build on a device, but I cannot test on a device that starts this until after rebooting the device. Also, I can still run tests on other devices (until the other devices start showing this same error).

Why would this be happening intermittently? I haven't found a specific way to reproduce it except for to continue running tests until it randomly occurs again.

Comment: Did you every find an answer for this question ?

Comment: No, I never did find a solution other than restarting the device. I haven't experienced this in Xcode 8 yet.